# Definition Simple Stochastic Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, definition

Can anybody explain what concretely is a ***simple*** (stochastic) process? 
(...and yes I tried to google it but without success)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple stochastic process $f$ on $[0,T]$ is one for which there exists times $0=t_1<t_1<t_2<\dots<t_n=T$ such that $f(t)$ is almost surely constant (in $t$) on each interval $[t_{i-1},t_i)$. This means that there are random variables $\xi_i,\dots,\xi_n$ such that
$$
f(t) = \sum_{i=1}^n\xi_i\cdot {\bf 1}_{[t_{i-1},t_i)}(t)
$$
Additionally, if there is a filtration $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$, then it is required that $f$ be adapted to this filtration, which is equivalent to saying that $\xi_i\in \mathcal F_{t_{i-1}}$.

Just like simple functions are used to define the integral in measure theory, simple processes are used to define the stochastic integral $\int f(t)\,dB_t$.

Comment: $\xi_{i} \in \mathcal{F}_{t_{i-1}}$ implies, that the process is predictable. Don't You mean, that $\xi_{i} \in \mathcal{F}_{t_{i}}$ is equivalent when $f$ is adapted to the filtration ?

Comment: If the process is adapted, then in particular $f(t_{i-1})\in \mathcal F_{t_{i-1}}$, which means that $\xi_{i}\in \mathcal F_{t_{i-1}}$. This does let you "look info the future" a bit, but if you were only given $\xi_i\in \mathcal F_{t_i}$, then you would never know the value of $f(t)$ at time $t$.